# Cigarette consumption dose-response function WRT health outcomes

Tags: human-biology, cancer, statistics, health, smoking

I'm curious how health risks (mortality, lifetime probability of cancer, etc) change with cigarette consumption.  Specifically, treatring cigarette consumption like a continuous variable, rather than a binary for "smokers" and "nonsmokers".  I've got access to academic literature, but I'm not a doctor or a PhD health researcher.  [This article](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2223525/) states in the abstract that the dose-response relationship between cigarettes and incidence of lung cancer is linear.  [This website](http://www.cdc.gov/tobacco/data_statistics/fact_sheets/health_effects/effects_cig_smoking/index.htm) (CDC) states that "smokers" have a 25-fold increase in risk of lung cancer.

How to reconcile the two?  The latter reports odds ratios, which means that they did a logistic regression, which means that the raw logistic regression coefficient was 3.2.  If the average smoker smokes 20 cigarettes a day, and the dose-response relationship is linear, then the relative risk for someone who smokes one per day should be exp(0.32) = 1.37.  So someone who smokes one cigarette per day would be 1.37 times more likely to get lung cancer than someone who never smoked (on average).

Is this a reasonable estimate?  I can certainly understand why public health types wouldn't promote this sort of conclusion, as smoking one cigarette can be a slipper slope to smoking a lot more cigarettes.

Comment: Personal medical questions are off-topic here. Could you edit your question to remove those implications? See http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Its a general population-level question with personal interest.  But if it bothers you, I'll lose the last paragraph.